# Materialize CSS Text Area Undefined When Passed As Object

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, materialize

Within a Google Sheet there's a sidebar that runs an HTML file that calls Materialize CSS. This sidebar contains three text inputs, work fine, and one text area that keeps failing and wondered if anyone had any thoughts. The text area's code:

```
<div class="row"><div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea1" 
class="materialize-textarea"></textarea><label for="textarea1">Further Details</label> 
</div></div>'
```

When the sidebar's submit button is click the following code is run:

```
 <input type="button" style="height:40px; width:100px; font-weight:bold;" 
 value="Send" onclick="google.script.run.sendEmail(this.parentNode);"/></form>'
```

For all three text input the data is pulled across to a function that uses it to send an email. However the text area comes out as:

```
 Further Details:

 undefined
```

The body code for the email is: (Condensed down)

```
var body = obj.textinput1+obj.textinput2+obj.textinput3+obj.textarea1
```

Have added Materialize's JS too

```
$('#textarea1').val('New Text');
M.textareaAutoResize($('#textarea1'));
```

Many thanks

Comment: How are you handling `this.parentNode` in `sendEmail`?  I've never sent a DOM object to google.script.run.  I typically extract the text or values I want and sent that to the server.

Comment: Function sendmail(obj)    Then extract data values via obj.inputID ie obj.username. Whilst this process was new to me would expect it to fully work with a mixture of text inputs/ text areas or not to

Comment: Have successfully done extract text and values into an array and send that over. However was interested if this method would work

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(obj)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textarea`'s `name` is not set. `id` isn't transferred, but `name`s become keys:

> [If you call a server function with a form element as a parameter, the form becomes a single object with **field names as keys** and field values as values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=en#forms)

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <!-- Here we set the name for #textarea1 -->
        <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea">
        </textarea>
        <label for="textarea1">
            Further Details
        </label> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How studiedly silly of me. Many thanks as this answer worked. Please let me buy you a coffee if you have that link

Comment: @DavidHowarth Glad to help.  You can contact me through my [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScue2TCQamJeeBiEgc5Qq0ChLo8GhyqbTcM1rLisppQysnh5g/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.979159126=I+would+like+to+contact+you+because+), if you're interested.